# Java 5 - Check whether a network interface is up and running.

Tags: java, network-programming

Java 6 offers isUp() method to check whether a network interface is up and running.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isUp()

Is there any way to check the same in Java 5?

Comment: Probably not, since it is a native call.

Comment: java5 still allows you to iterate your network interfaces and get their IP addresses. You could internally ping each one to see if you get a reply or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to see whether *any* resource is available, from an NIC to a database to a Web server on the other side of the world, or the Moon, is to *try to use it.* Any other technique is liable to the timing problem that it was up when you tested and down when you used it, or the other way around. And when you try to use it you have to deal with the failure cases anyway, because they are generally checked exceptions: why write the same code twice?

Answer (score 1):

If you won't mind using an external library, check [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar)

You can get the network interface status, among with stats like bytes received or bytes sent.

The only fallback is that is a C library with a java binding, so you will need the specific version for your architecture at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Class `NetworkInterface` has a method `getInetAddresses()`, delivering an enumeration of `InetAddress`-es. Assuming each adapter supports IPv4, you'll find an `Inet4Address` among these. if the interface is down it will deliver "0.0.0.0" as address, by method `toString()`. If an Adapter is up but not linked (no dynamic address assigned), it will have an address of pattern "169.x.x.x".